# How do I change the sequence on my To Do app with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm working on a To Do App with JavaScript and I want to make a HttpRequest. It doesn't work well because I can see the data at the very end of the console so my GET request isn't work properly. How can I switch them to have the GET request at the end of the program?

Here is the data response:

```
let url = 'here is my url';
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onloadend = (event) => {
            return xhr.result;
};
```

I set the header thus:

```
setHeader() {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
}
```

My get function looks like this:

```
get(async, header) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xhr.open('GET', url, async);
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
        xhr.send();
        resolve(xhr.response);
    });
}
```

I must use HttpClient and JavaScript, I cannot use jQuery or anything else.

Comment: Those three snippets don't look like they are part of a single script; can you show your actual code, including how you're calling `get()`? And what do you mean by `have the GET request at the end of the program`? I can't make any sense of that.

Comment: I agree with the above. If you can reproduce this on a fiddler/pen or at least paste the data that you see at the very end of the console.

Comment: let items = []; 
getAll() {
        httpClient.get(true, this.header).then((result) => {
            const data = !!result ? result : '[]';
            const items = JSON.parse(data);
            items.forEach(item => {
                const todo = new Todo(item.id, item.name, item.status);
                items.push(todo);
            });
        });
    }
 I use the "get" request here first, and i want it to run after the "onloadend" function.

Comment: @vargaadam Are you using React or Angular or Vue ?

Comment: @JayVaghasiya I use Vanilla Javascript

Comment: https://codepen.io/vargaadam19/pen/OJJqEgX?editors=0010
 There are two classes of queries. Here is the corrected version

Comment: @vargaadam so you want to use get method of HttpClient class in TodoList class ?

Comment: Yes I want @JayVaghasiya

Answer (score 0):

Please bind getAll function in constructor OR you can use **Arrow function**

```
export class HttpClient {
  constructor(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.onloadend = event => {
      console.log("ONLOADEND", this.xhr.response);
      return this.xhr.result;
    };

    this.setHeader = this.setHeader.bind(this);
    this.get = this.get.bind(this);
    this.post = this.post.bind(this);
  }

  setHeader() {
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }

  get(async, header) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.xhr.open("GET", this.url, async);
      this.xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
      this.xhr.send();
      console.log("xhr", this.xhr.response);
      resolve(this.xhr.response);
      // return nothing
    });
  }

  post(async, data, header) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.xhr.open("POST", this.url + "create", async);
      this.setHeader(header);
      this.xhr.send(data);
      console.log("RESPONSE", this.xhr.response);
      resolve(this.xhr.response);
    });
  }
}

export class TodoList extends HttpClient {
  constructor() {
    super("http://todoapp.test/api/");
    this.items = [];
    this.header = new Headers();
    this.header.set("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");

    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.getAll = this.getAll.bind(this);
  }

  add(todo) {
    this.post(true, JSON.stringify(todo), this.header);
    this.items.push(todo);
  }

  getAll() {
    this.get(true, this.header).then(result => {
      const data = !!result ? result : "[]";
      const items = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log("result:", result);
      items.forEach(item => {
        const todo = new Todo(item.id, item.name, item.status);
        this.items.push(todo);
      });
      console.log("items block:", this.items);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/vargaadam19/pen/BaabVbZ?editors=0010
There are two classes of queries. Here is the corrected version. @JayVaghasiya

Comment: @vargaadam still you need to bind right ? without binding you can not access constructor in any functions OR if you dont want to bind please use **Arrow function** can you please provide what is error ?

Comment: The problem still occurs with your version, sadly. The answers in the console appear in the following order:

   xhr 
   result: 
   items block: []
   ONLOADEND
And i would like the following order:
   ONLOADEND
   xhr 
   result: 
   items block: []

Comment: todo-list.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at TodoList.getAll (todo-list.js:34)
    at TodoApp.load (todo-app.js:100)
    at index.js:4

This will not load the 'get' function in my "getAll" function.

Comment: @vargaadam now i think its binding issue please bind all functions in constructor like `this.getAll = this.getAll.bind(this);` also i have updated my code please check constructor f both class

Comment: The problem remains, with this solution, the function does not recognize the get function. @JayVaghasiya

Comment: @vargaadam Can you please create a codepen of last code

Comment: https://codepen.io/vargaadam19/pen/MWWxqLp?editors=0010 Here is the last code. @JayVaghasiya

Comment: @vargaadam please check my code i have removed httpClient in TodoList class, now it is only this.get and this.post

Comment: ohh first round I didn't see it sorry, but the sequence again not good, the onloadend function is at the very end. @JayVaghasiya

Comment: @vargaadam when you extends other class you can directly access other class methods

Comment: my problem is that the command line does not start with the 'onloadend' task.

Comment: @vargaadam i have no idea about Vanilla JS so i am unable to provide you help further, sorry

Comment: Thanks you for your time @vargaadam

Comment: WOW, I would rather prefer Instagram

Comment: Sorry but you provide your profile, sorry but i have trust issue  @vargaadam

Comment: @vargaadam Please delete last comment please check i am following you Thanks